# Realtime Audio Convolution on Android

Tags: android, audio, android-service, fft, convolution

I'm trying to design an Android app that will start a service which applies a reverb (using convolution) to any audio played through the phone *regardless of the app the audio is coming from*. The service would ideally run in the background and enable the reverb effect as soon as audio begins to play on the device.

Is something like this possible on a non rooted Android device, and if it is, where's the best place to get started?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without root access.
There is some example of real time convolution such as viper4android fx though it uses linux native driver to achive the problem.